# Terraform -replace single resource on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, terraform

Terraform - I have two resources in azure pipeline YML file

1. Docker image pushed into Azure Container Registry (docker image is STRAPI image)
2. App service creation using the docker image

I want to replace the docker image every time there are new or modified files in STRAPI code (File system), how can I use -replace command here. any suggestions?

currently the terraform plan doesn't identify any changes to the file system and throws following message in the TERRAFORM-PLAN

> No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
>
> ```
> Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration
> and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
> ```

**UPDATED with Code:

1. Below is the code in my main.tf file**

```
resource "null_resource" "docker_push_strapiaa" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
    docker login ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server} --username ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_username} --password ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_password}
    docker build . -t ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/${var.strapi_image} -f strapi.Dockerfile --platform linux/amd64
    docker push ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/${var.strapi_image}     
    EOT
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to add the code you are using in order for us to understand what is going on. In theory, you should replace the image referenced after it is built but I don't know too much based on the question.

Comment: I have added code to the main post

Comment: Ok, so since you are using `null_resource` why not run the azure CLI command to update the image in it?

Comment: I use below command to Build the image
                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
docker build . -t ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/${var.strapi_image} -f strapi.Dockerfile --platform linux/amd64

Comment: @MarkoE The resource "null_resource" "docker_push_strapiaa" will not be build if there are no changes, I want to force deploy "null_resource"

Comment: I am unable to find any answer on this? can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this, this works fine and docker image is re-built every time pipeline works

```
 resource "null_resource" "docker_push_strapi" {
    
      triggers = {
        always_run = "${timestamp()}"
      }
      
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<-EOT
            docker login ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server} --username ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_username} --password ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_password}
            docker build . -t ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/${var.strapi_image} -f strapi.Dockerfile --platform linux/amd64
            docker push ${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/${var.strapi_image}
          EOT
      }
    }
```